# Set multiple attributes on basis of results of a :select in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select box on my form which retreives an object with the following attributes:

```
:id, :v2_read_code, :v2_term
```

The select code is:

```
f.inputs "Tests" do
  f.has_many :eqa_material_tests, :allow_destroy => true, :heading => 'Tests In EQA Material' do |cf|
    cf.input :test_id, :as => :select, :collection => Hash[Test.all.order(default: :asc).map{|b| [b.v2_term,b.id]}]
  end
end
```

Where I am storing the test id in a model/table with the following structure:

**eqa_material_tests**

id, test_id, eqa_material_id

In addition to storing the **test_id**, I'd also like to store the **v2_read_code** and **v2_term** as I'd like to keep a copy of these items if possible.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

After a nights sleep I've realised I'm approaching this wrong. I can do this using an active record callback like after_create